# Will jQuery or AJAX make HTML "required" attribute invalid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm now constructing a registration page and have labeled username and password inputs as required. Simple code as:

```html
Username <input id="username" type="text" required/>
Password <input id="username" type="password" required/>
<button id="register">Register</button>
<div id="registerOutput></div>
```

When I just run those code with pure HTML on localhost the "required" would function properly. But once I include a register.js file which I made to get the data and use AJAX to send data to register.php, the required attribute seems not working. In register.js, simple code as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").on("click", function(){

        var username        = $("#username").val();
        var password        = $("#password").val();

        var userData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "register.php?",
            data: userData,
            success: function(backData){
                $("#registerOutput").html(backData);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Can anybody tell me the reason why jQuery would override the functionality of required? How to surpass it or if it must override, how should I do the same thing in my jQuery code?

Comment: JavaScript at Question does not validate input values. You can use form.checkValidity() where pattern attribute value matches input value

Comment: Instead of using `click` event to run ajax and send data via ajax, you should use `onsubmit` on form, so that HTML5 can validate form first before submitting and then your ajax function will work. Let me know if you need code example as answer

Comment: Thanks for your help @guest271314 I will check form.checkValidity() out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MaheshSinghChouhan I've checked out onsubmit and realized the way you were indicating! I will use onsubmit on forms from now on :)

Comment: FYI, the /> syntax is a holdover from XHTML, but the minimized attribute syntax is not valid XHTML. For the sake of consistency, choose either `required>` (HTML syntax) or `required="required"/>` (XHTML syntax). Mixing and matching is allowed in HTML5, but it is akin to [semantic nonsense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) and should be avoided if you want your markup to look professional.

Comment: Hi @BoltClock thanks for your information and yes this is a problem I was really confused. Before this project I always wrote input tag as <input> without a /> since it doesn't have a closing tag, but not until I see somebody writes input tag as <input/> I searched the web and was directed to this page: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/4fedcb1b6a5e31000302412a From here somebody addressed a similar opinion with yours. I will just put it here as my reference and future readers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to redesign your code a little bit. There is a way to follow HTML convenience and yet use full power of AJAX.

I edited your example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/myezf63b/

So here is modified HTML:

```
<form id="form">
  Username <input id="username" type="text" required/>
  Password <input id="username" type="password" required/>
  <button type="submit" id="register">Register</button>
</form>

<div id="registerOutput">
</div>
```

Basically I added `type="submit"` to button and wrapped it inside form.

and this is modified jQuery code:

I added `e.preventDefault()` which prevents website from redirecting (reloading page) and as event I used `submit` which follows this pattern.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var username        = $("#username").val();
    var password        = $("#password").val();

    var userData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
        console.log('test')
    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "register.php?",
        data: userData,
        success: function(backData){
            $("#registerOutput").html(backData);
        }
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Kunok! Your code not only solves my "required" problem but also taught me a more proper way to write those code. I will search on e.preventDefault() and learn! 

Comment: May I also ask that why are you using "$("#form").on("submit", function(e)" instead of using "$("#register").on("click", function(e)"? What do you mean by "as event I used submit which follows this pattern"? Was this saying related to  "$("#form").on("submit","?

Comment: Also, another newbie question is why did you add a type="submit" for <button>? Is that only for semantic reason? Sorry I'm still kinda new in this field...

Comment: @Hang Instead of adding event to the button, I added event to the form element. That is because you are submitting form, not a button. It may allow you further extension of your form functionalities. Basically you don't need to add `type="submit"` but in some cases you will have multiple buttons, and this might be useful to know that this is the submit button. Basically this is the way I do things in other libraries like React and I love universal approaches. Also, my suggestion would be adding validations on PHP and JS level too, for security and UX purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kunok that is a really good habit and practice in the development process. I will learn this from you. And yea I definitely will add validations on PHP and JS later before I finalize this project :D